# STR_TO_DATE from CONCAT

Tags: mysql, concatenation, str-to-date

I have one date-field `ref_event_times`.`end_date` and one time-field `ref_event_times`.`end_time` in my table "ref_event_times"...

I try to union that as a one datetime field "end_date_time"...
Use follow

```
STR_TO_DATE('CONCAT(`ref_event_times`.`end_date`,' ',`ref_event_times`.`end_time`)','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') AS `end_date_time`
```

return null...

Where is the mistake?

Comment: try `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(ref_event_times.end_date,' ',ref_event_times.end_time),'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')`  this one

Comment: TRY THIS I CHECKED ITS WORKING select STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(current_date,' ',current_time),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');

Comment: STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`ref_event_times`.`end_date`,' ',`ref_event_times`.`end_time`),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')

Finaly need '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' 
More thanks

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL doesn't support your given datetime format `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'`

The mysql date format should be like this `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'` [Datetime format in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html)

```
    Data Type   “Zero” Value
    DATE        '0000-00-00'
    TIME        '00:00:00'
    DATETIME    '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    TIMESTAMP   '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    YEAR        0000
```

try this example

```
select STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(current_date,' ',current_time),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```